# SQL Server Query - Format Output

Tags: sql-server-2012

Question to folks that are more experienced in writing SQL scripts. I am rather new to writing SQL, we migrated to SQL from a UniData environment last year. My question is can you format the output from a SQL Script to not just rows and columns, see below what a vendor who provides a 3rd party solution, called MAXIENT. We are a college and they want a weekly output to import into their database for the app. we use in this form.

```
Student ID#[CR-LF] (first line, same record)
Course Description     Meeting Days(MWF)     Times(9-10am)     Instructor Name [CR-LF] (next 4-5 lines, same record)
********** (10 asterisks to divide each record, last line of record)
Student ID#[CR-LF] (next record)
Course Description     Meeting Days(MWF)     Times(8:30-10:15am)  Instructor
.....
....
...
```

..
.

and so forth

Comment: Are you writing a program to do this?  Reporting services?  Just a select query in SSMS?  More info please.

Comment: Typically it's the job of your presentation layer not your data layer to format output.

Comment: No! SQL Server is purely a database engine. You can use C#, or any other programming language with ODBC connection, to format the results. Also, check if that Maxient software works with SQL Server.